# Google Maps API stopped working in Wordpress Template

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-maps

So my Google Maps API WAS working and now it's not. Looking through the documentation on Google's Maps API I don't see that anything has changed. We're using the maps embedded in a Wordpress PHP Template and everything I've checked seems to be right. Has something changed?

Here's the initial code:

```
<section id="main">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBqnue6HpFD-HQvnk_cOKTQmqAzE6Xb9NQ"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.americanraceronline.com/wp-content/uploads/dev/markerwithlabel.js"></script>

<script type="application/javascript" >
  var map;
  var infoWindow;
  function initialize() {
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.6,-95.665);
  var myOptions = {
     center: myLatLng,
      scrollwheel: true,
   navigationControl: false,
   mapTypeControl: false,
   scaleControl: true,
   draggable: true,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.Whitewater,
                      styles:[/lots of styles here/]};
var poly;

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
myOptions);

var marker1 = new MarkerWithLabel({
   position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.27488643704891, -110.740234375),
   draggable: false,
   raiseOnDrag: false,
   map: map,
   labelContent: "WEST",
   labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 2),
   labelClass: "mylabels", // the CSS class for the label
   labelStyle: {opacity: 1.0},
    icon: {}
 });
```

The link to the page is: http://www.americanraceronline.com/distributors/

What am I missing?

Comment: You have to be more clear when you ask a question. For example, you say it doesn't work: How it doesn't work? Is there an error message? Or... Anyways, try Firebug with Firefox. It will probably show lots of Javascript errors for this code and it will help you fix it.

Comment: The map simply doesn't appear. I've looked at the JS errors, and the one referenced below has always appeared on the page - it's not something new.

Comment: Your map has javascript errors: `Uncaught InvalidValueError: setIcon: not a string; and no url property; and no path property` (among others).

Comment: On your webpage (but not in your posted code), you have multiple functions with the same name (`initialize`).  I find it hard to believe that ever could have worked as expected.  Please post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your browser console:

> You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.main.js:60 yl

This does not need much explanation: you must be including the `Google API` repeated, check your includes to contain API reference only once.

*Maybe file main.js, line:60 ??*

Comment: Yes that error has always been on the page and it never affected the map before. To be honest I'm not sure where that main.js is called from in the Wordpress template.

Answer (score 0):

For Google Maps mapOptions, `zoom` is required (see [reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions)), e.g.

```
var myOptions = {
   center: myLatLng,
   scrollwheel: true,
   navigationControl: false,
   mapTypeControl: false,
   scaleControl: true,
   draggable: true,
   disableDefaultUI: true,
   zoom: 9,
   styles:[/lots of styles here/]
};
```

For example, I created a simple [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bobdye/d585dL2d/) of your code that did not work until zoom was provided.

Comment: Ok that's an improvement - but I'm still missing ALL of the polygon shapes. These worked last week, but not this week. Suggestions?